# Receive data from uart with Raspberry Pi mono c#

Tags: serial, raspbian-wheezy, uart, mono

From today, after updating libraries Mono C# on my Raspberry Pi Rev 2 Type B (wheezy), the communication via serial no longer works, it seems to me very strange, because yesterday with the same program written in C # the serial communication worked fine.

To make sure that it was not a hardware problem, I installed "screen" on raspberry and writing the line: sudo screen / dev/ttyAMA0 9600, it can receive data from the serial port, so I think it's a problem of the mono libraries after the upgrade. What do you think? I do not really know what it could be, I have tried everything below. 
I'll post the code for the test program:

```
public static SerialPort mySerial = new SerialPort("/dev/ttyAMA0", 9600, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    mySerial.Open();
    string readed = "";
    while (true)
    {
        try
        {
            if (true)
            {
                if (mySerial.BytesToRead > 0)
                {
                    readed = mySerial.ReadLine();
                    Console.WriteLine("Ho Letto: " + readed);
                 }
            }
        }
        catch (TimeoutException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Errore nella lettura");
        }
        finally
        {
            //
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks for the help that you give me